# What's wrong with a new installation of Drupal 8.6.10?

Tags: 8

A fresh install of Drupal results in a WSOD including a very helpful error message which says "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

I normally install Drupal with the drupal-project template from github and at first, I thought this was a problem with my local DDEV environment. I then tried with MAMP Pro to find exactly the same.

Finally I tried on simplytest.me to realise that it isn't me.

A look at my local error logs reports the following;

```
"NOTICE: PHP message: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig\Error\SyntaxError: 
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template 
("Attribute "name" does not exist for Node 
Twig\Node\CheckToStringNode) in 
core/themes/bartik/templates/block--system-menu-block.html.twig"." at 
/var/www/html/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php line 
797"
```

I found that is was possible to access the site via the admin path, and changing the theme to Stark allowed me to view the site.

I then attempted to view recent system messages at admin/reports/dblog - only to once again to get the "Please try again later" message.

Answer (score 0):

Twig version 1.38.1 is broken (or not D8 compatible)

Revert to 1.37.1

Comment: Then Drupal 8.6.10 is broken too?

Comment: Yup @MrPaulDriver :)